# how to add property of undefined or reference in IE11

Tags: javascript, html, css

//if the return value is undefined, then it must be "cancel". Please provide any useful information on this issue .
    This issue is occurring when we are trying to launch the jsp page in IE11 browser in the return flow.

```
    //if the return value is undefined, then it must be "cancel"
    if (typeof returnValue == "null") {
        document.getElementById("user").value = "cancel";
    } else {
        //set value of various form elements, based on returnValue
    }

    postCommand(null, "redirect", "serversideredirect", "", "");
}

</script>
```

Comment: It means that one of the elements you expect to exist actually doesn't. Your code should be checking that the return values from `getElementById()` are not `null`.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to execute ...

```
 document.getElementById("userAction").value = "cancelled";
```

When the id in the Body is ... **lblAction**

```
<b><label style="HEIGHT:25px; FONT-SIZE:12pt" id="lblAction"></label></b>
```

The two should match.

**UPDATE:**

```
document.getElementById("userAction").value = "cancelled";
```

... should become

```
document.getElementById("lblAction").value = "cancelled";'
```

Comment: 'document.getElementById("userAction").value = "cancelled";' should become 'document.getElementById("lblAction").value = "cancelled";'